# How do I know if my project is deployed and running in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, database-migration

I have given a project to a development company of 2 mobile apps and 2 website, they claim that they have migrated the code from theirs to my aws account. Upon checking I see an EC2 instance running in my account. I would like to know if my project containing 2 websites and 2 mobile apps are running in my aws. I also see usage with 0 bill. Or is there any other way to confirm that the code has been successfully deployed into my aws account.

Answer (score 0):

Please ask the development company! No one here can see what is happening in your own AWS environment.

Just a few things:

- You receive bills monthly (0 bills now seems fine).
- You can find your current occurring costs in the AWS Cost Explorer.
- And the code could be running on any of the various compute services (ECS, EKS, EB, Lambda,...) AND in any of the over 20 AWS regions.